# Tab control's tab item header in wpf

Tags: wpf, user-controls, observablecollection, tabcontrol

I have a tab control in a WPF Window. TabControl's Item source is bound to `ObservableCollection<UserControl>` in its view model.

So how can I set my TabControl's each TabItem's tab header?

Since my tab item type is of my `UserControl` not a `TabItem` I can not set as:

```
((TabItem)Tabcontrol.Item[0]).Header="Something"
```

Do some one have the solution?

My `TabControl` is:

```
<TabControl Name="TabControl" Grid.Row="1" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding TabCollection}"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentIndex}" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a style for each TabItem that will set a binding to a property called `Header` on your user controls. Try this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
</Style>
```

Each control you add to the tabitem will need a property call Header. It *does not have to be declared on an interface for the binding to work*.

Here is a full example using your tab control.

```
<TabControl Name="TabControl" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding TabCollection}"  SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentIndex}"  >
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Title}"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

The style is automatically applied by WPF.

Comment: It is not updating my ui. I added the code as <TabControl Name="TabControl" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding TabCollection}"  SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentIndex}"  >
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>
        </TabControl>............................ Do I need to mention my user control's view model any where?

Comment: One way or another, you want to extract the data from the view model. If the viewmodel is the data context for your user control, change the binding to say {Binding DataContext.Header}